# Field with index 0 exceeds the size limit of 32000 bytes,dremio

Tags: dremio

I have googled and read articles from the community, but I still can't solve this.

This is my job profile, https://community.dremio.com/uploads/short-url/edtC2D5EKmhPJViVSEo4V5RbGAe.zip

I don’t know what “Field with index 0” means which field in the picture, the data source is like the following:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your 1st field (the field with index 0) has 1 or more values exceeded 32000 bytes, which is Dremio's size limit for a data value.

You probably need to find and exclude that row of value, or try to cast the column to VARCHAR